# Twitter Just Text(status/tweet)

Tags: php, json, twitter

Am actually working on a small twitter project. For which I need just the status i.e the tweets to be saved into a .txt file based upon the search. For now am only able to get the json form of my search to be saved into the .txt file. Am not good with json as I've never worked with it before. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
if ( isset( $tweets->errors[0]->code )) {
    // If errors exist, print the first error for a simple notification.
    echo "Error encountered: ".$tweets->errors[0]->message." Response code:" .$tweets->errors[0]->code;
 }else {
    // No errors exist. Write tweets to json/txt file.
    $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$_POST['keyword'].'&lang=en&result_type=recent&count=2');
    $file = "searchtweets.txt";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, json_encode($tweets));
    fclose($fh);


}
?>
```

Am getting the following in the searchtweets.txt file:

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent",
        "iso_language_code": "en"
      },
      "created_at": "Mon Jul 21 18:17:25 +0000 2014",
      "id": 4.912858338579e+17,
      "id_str": "491285833857904641",
      "text": "Do the rest later FIFA",
      "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
      "truncated": false,
      "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
      "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
      "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
      "user": {
        "id": 1523422004,
        "id_str": "1523422004",
        "name": "Mathers",
        "screen_name": "MichaelGardnerr",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
          "description": {
            "urls": [

            ]
          }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 555,
        "friends_count": 510,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Jun 16 22:56:26 +0000 2013",
        "favourites_count": 5932,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 7567,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "131516",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000161948327\/NcME2CFH.jpeg",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000161948327\/NcME2CFH.jpeg",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/486264708174209024\/WitFpexv_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/486264708174209024\/WitFpexv_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1523422004\/1401822572",
        "profile_link_color": "009999",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false
      },
      "geo": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          51.93107788,
          0.20016287
        ]
      },
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0.20016287,
          51.93107788
        ]
      },
      "place": {
        "id": "3bc1b6cfd27ef7f6",
        "url": "https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/3bc1b6cfd27ef7f6.json",
        "place_type": "admin",
        "name": "East",
        "full_name": "East, United Kingdom",
        "country_code": "GB",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "contained_within": [

        ],
        "bounding_box": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                -0.74577980081805,
                51.448222132109
              ],
              [
                1.7689359995018,
                51.448222132109
              ],
              [
                1.7689359995018,
                52.992678957625
              ],
              [
                -0.74577980081805,
                52.992678957625
              ]
            ]
          ]
        },
        "attributes": {

        }
      },
      "contributors": null,
      "retweet_count": 0,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": [

        ],
        "symbols": [

        ],
        "urls": [

        ],
        "user_mentions": [

        ]
      },
      "favorited": false,
      "retweeted": false,
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "search_metadata": {
    "completed_in": 0.008,
    "max_id": 4.912858338579e+17,
    "max_id_str": "491285833857904641",
    "next_results": "?max_id=491285833857904640&q=fifa&lang=en&count=1&include_entities=1&result_type=recent",
    "query": "fifa",
    "refresh_url": "?since_id=491285833857904641&q=fifa&lang=en&result_type=recent&include_entities=1",
    "count": 1,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
  }
}
```

I only want 'Do the rest later FIFA' in the searchtweets.txt from "text": "Do the rest later FIFA", above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved what I was looking for.

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        foreach($tweet as $t){
            $output = $t->text;
            fwrite($fh, $output);
```

this has done it. Now I am able to save only the tweets into my .txt